# Using NearestNeighbors and word2vec to detect sentence similarity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, word2vec

I have calculated a word2vec model using python and `gensim` in my corpus.

Then I calculated the mean word2vec vector for each sentence (averaging all the vectors for all the words in the sentence) and stored it in a pandas data frame.
The columns of the pandas data frame `df` are:

- sentence
- Book title (the book where the sentence comes from)
- mean-vector (the mean of the word2vec vectors in the sentence - size 100)

I am trying to use `scikit-learn` `NearestNeighbors` to detect sentence similarity (I could probably use doc2vec instead, but one of the objectives is to compare this method against doc2vec).

This is my code:

```
X = df['mean_vector'].values
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think somehow I should iterate the vectors, to be able to calculate on a `row == sentence` basis the nearest neighbours of each row, but it seems this exceeds my current (limited) python skills.

This is the data  of the first cell in `df['mean_vector'][0]`.  It is a full vector size 100 averaged over the vectors of the sentence.

```
array([ -2.14208905e-02,   2.42093615e-02,  -5.78106642e-02,
     1.32915592e-02,  -2.43393257e-02,  -1.41872400e-02,
     2.83471867e-02,  -2.02910602e-02,  -5.49359620e-02,
    -6.70913085e-02,  -5.56188896e-02,  -2.95186806e-02,
     4.97652516e-02,   7.16793686e-02,   1.81338750e-02,
    -1.50108105e-02,   1.79438610e-02,  -2.41483524e-02,
     4.97504435e-02,   2.91026086e-02,  -6.87966943e-02,
     3.27585079e-02,   5.10644279e-02,   1.97029337e-02,
     7.73109496e-02,   3.23865712e-02,  -2.81659551e-02,
    -9.69715789e-03,   5.23059331e-02,   3.81100960e-02,
    -3.62489261e-02,  -3.40068117e-02,  -4.90736961e-02,
     8.72346922e-04,   2.27111522e-02,   1.06063476e-02,
    -3.93234752e-02,  -1.10617064e-01,   8.05142429e-03,
     4.56497036e-02,  -1.73281748e-02,   2.35153548e-02,
     5.13465842e-03,   1.88336968e-02,   2.40451116e-02,
     3.79024050e-03,  -4.83284928e-02,   2.10295208e-02,
    -4.92134318e-03,   1.01532964e-02,   8.02216958e-03,
    -6.74675079e-03,  -1.39653292e-02,  -2.07276996e-02,
     9.73508134e-03,  -7.37899616e-02,  -2.58320477e-02,
    -1.10700730e-05,  -4.53227758e-02,   2.31859135e-03,
     1.40053956e-02,   1.61973312e-02,   3.01702786e-02,
    -6.96818605e-02,  -3.47468331e-02,   4.79541793e-02,
    -1.78820305e-02,   5.99209731e-03,  -5.92620336e-02,
     7.34678581e-02,  -5.23381204e-05,  -5.07357903e-02,
    -2.55154949e-02,   5.06089740e-02,  -3.70467864e-02,
    -2.04878468e-02,  -7.62404222e-03,  -5.38200373e-03,
     7.68705690e-03,  -3.27000804e-02,  -2.18365286e-02,
     2.34392099e-03,  -3.02998684e-02,   9.42565035e-03,
     3.24523374e-02,  -1.10793915e-02,   3.06244520e-03,
    -1.82240941e-02,  -5.70741761e-03,   3.13486941e-02,
    -1.15621388e-02,   1.10221673e-02,  -3.55655849e-02,
    -4.56304513e-02,   5.54837054e-03,   4.38252240e-02,
     1.57828294e-02,   2.65670624e-02,   8.08797963e-03,
     4.55569401e-02], dtype=float32)
```

I have also tried to do:

```
for vec in df['mean_vector']:
X = vec
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
```

But I only get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

If there is an example on github using word2vec and `NearestNeighbors` in a similar scenario I would love to see it.

Comment: how does X look like? can you update question with sample X?

Comment: Need some data for a MWE. I just tested `NearestNeighbors` using data from `gensim` and it worked fine for me though.

Comment: @Abhishek Thakur I've added an example vector (there is one for each sentence in the corpus, so it is quite a number).

Comment: @ncfirth I would love to see your example if available... thanks

Comment: Hi @Enzo I am currently working on a similar project where I store sentences as the average of the w2v vectors of the words in that sentence and then use KNN to find the closest sentences when a keyword/phrase is entered. 

Could you tell me what's a good way to evaluate such models? Because I do not have any classes per-se. I wanted to try out a few different distance metrics (for NN) to see which one works best but I wanted to have a reliable to way to know whether or not the model is improving with each change I make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your edit is throwing an error is because `sklearn` expects a 2D input, with each example being in a new row. You can either use `X.reshape(1, -1)` or `[X]`, the first is better practice. Without the raw data or a proper MWE it's hard to say exactly is going wrong, but my guess is that something is going wrong with either putting the data in or out of the dataframe. Check that `X.shape` makes sense to you.

Below is the example I used to check everything worked for me:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import numpy as np

a = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum."""
a = [x.split(' ') for x in a.split('\n') if len(x)]
model = Word2Vec(a, min_count=1)

# Get the average of all of the words to get data for a sentence
b = np.array([np.mean([model[xx] for xx in x], axis=0) for x in a])
# Check it's the correct shape
print b.shape

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(b)
```

Comment: I guess my issue is that I'm using a pandas dataframe to store the mean vectors. `print(df['mean_vector'].shape)` gives `(67680,)` but `X = df['mean_vector'].reshape(1, -1)` and `nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)` still gives `setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: How many sentences are there in your dataframe, 67680? If so then one would expect the size of `X` to return `(67680,100)`

Comment: Looking at your example (very useful!), I am sort of thinking that the problem is in the shape of my data frame. Not sure how to fix it...

Comment: To be sure the dataframe shape is OK: `print(df.shape)` gives `(67680, 4)`, rows and column. In your example `b.shape` gives (5,100). Very different! I have 67680 sentences, and the mean wordvec (a tuple with 100 entries) is stored in the same row of the sentence, which fits with my intuition. In the other hand I'm not clear on `b.shape`.

Comment: `b.shape` is the number of sentences x the length of your features (100), so if I had as many examples as you it would return `(67680,100)`. The shape of `df` is fine, you're interested in `df['mean_vector'].shape` as that's what is going in to the `fit` function.